# Having a difficult time understanding callback functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, function, callback

I'm new to JavaScript and i'm having difficulties understanding callback functions.

I have a function below that returns an array and then another function that calls the first function. Problem is, the array in the second function is always undefined, even though in the first function is returns an array of objects.

```
    function getItems() {
        $.get(url,
            function(data) {
                var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                var itemArr = $.map(obj, function(ele) { return ele; })
                return itemArr;
            });
    }


    function alertTest() {
        var items = getItems();
        alert(items);
    }
```

I understand that the first function is asynchronous and so that the alert in the second function is called before the returned array, which causes the second function to alert an undefined object.

I'm aware there is quite some documentation around this but i'm having trouble understanding how it works. Could someone show me the changes i would need to make so that the alertTest function returns the populated array after the getItems function has been called?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The second function should really return an array if the first one does return one as well, if you need to make this working, you can try to change lines in function alertTest() with "alert(getItems())" it will work the same way you imagined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this would be to use JS Promises like so

```
function getItems() {
    return Promise.resolve(
        $.get(url,
            function (data) {
                var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                var itemArr = $.map(obj, function (ele) {
                    return ele;
                })
                return itemArr;
            }));
}

function alertTest() {
    var items = getItems().then(function (items) {
        alert(items);
    });
}
```

It is a hard one to get your head around. Promises allow you to write code that runs in a sequence like sync code.

You could insert callbacks into the function and have that call when the get request finishes like shown in the other answer by Rhea but this is a cleaner way to do this and Promises are now part of the Javascript language.

Comment: The `return Promise.resolve(` is unnecessary. Just `return $.get(` will do the same thing.

Comment: That will return a deffered I beleive which is not Promise a++

Comment: Same contract as a `Promise` though. But, true.

Comment: No problem. Can you press the tick next to the answer to mark it as correct if you think it is the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

`$.get` is an `async` function. which means the `callback` function is invoked when  the  is hit and the response is returned inside .

Now `return itemArr` is actually returned by the callback function and 
`getItems()` doesn't actually return anything and hence it is always undefined.

For your code to work,

```
  function getItems() {
    $.get(url,
        function(data) {
            var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
            var itemArr = $.map(obj, function(ele) { return ele; })
            alertTest(itemArr); 
            return itemArr;
        });
  }
```

this would call `alertTest` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getItems() {
    $.get(url, function(data) {
        var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
        var itemArr = $.map(obj, function(ele) { return ele; })
        alertTest(itemArr);
    });
}      

function alertTest(items) {
    alert(items);
}

getItems();
```